# Java 8 Stream collect : Use a custom groupingBy function with collectingAndThen

Tags: java-8

Considering the following valid code :

```
    Map<CarType, Car> map3 = CarCollection.getList().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Car::getCarType,
                    collectingAndThen(
                            maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getHp)),
                            Optional::get)
            ));
```

Is it possible to customize the groupingBy function using the function below ?

```
public enum CarClass {
    eco,
    regular,
    gas_waste
}

    //classification function
    Function<Car, CarClass> groupingByCarClass =
            (c -> {
                if(c.getHp() <= 50) {
                    return CarClass.eco;
                } else if(c.getHp() > 50 && c.getHp() < 150) {
                    return CarClass.regular;
                } else {
                    return CarClass.gas_waste;
                }
            });
```

The following code is not valid :

```
    Map<CarType, Car> map3 = CarCollection.getList().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(groupingByCarClass,
                    collectingAndThen(
                            maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getHp)),
                            Optional::get)
            ));
```

Something is wrong but it's above my current xp with streams/lambdas

Comment: what do you mean by `The following code is not valid`? What is the error you get?

Comment: It does not compile ; the returned type is not the expected Map (instead some lamdba?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell where your problem is (besides the fact that in one place you use `CarClass::gas_waste` and in the other `CarClass::gas_sucker`, I'll assume these are the same), not to mention naming conventions... But in either case, what you have done can be simplified to:

```
Map<CarClass, Car> map3 = CarCollection.getList().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    groupingByCarClass,
                    Function.identity(),
                    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getHp))));
```

If you feel that you might need to use `Collectors.collectingAndThen(maxBy/minBy..., Optional::get)`, you probably want to use `Collectors.toMap(...)` with a merger as `BinaryOperator.maxBy`

Comment: thanks for replying ; CarClass gas_waste/gas_sucker was a mistake when copying code to SO. Underscore is forbidden in enums ?

Comment: @ObscurMoirage by any means it is not forbidden, but usually it's upper case

Comment: @ObscurMoirage btw is there anything else I might be missing in my answer?

Comment: No, it seems a nice answer. I think I was confused by the groupingBy() factory method which is not usable with this kind of construction. I'm currently reading Java 8 in action and trying to apply examples to my own collections, and sometimes mix them and extend features. This times it was requiring something different. Thanks !

Comment: yup sorry for that :)